# How to Set data dynamic array From SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, arraylist

## How to set data from SQL Server in C#.

My Class Student:

```
public class student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

## And I want to Set Data From SQL

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Student";
cmd.Connection = con;
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(datatable);
con.Close();
sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
{
    //Set Data: ex: student[] students=new student[];
    //students=new students{StudentID=dr["ID"],FirstName=dr["FirstName"]}
    // ...
}
```

## And My Code Set Data

```
namespace WebApi2.myapi
{
public class StudentController : ApiController
{
    student[] students = new student[]
     {
         new student { StudentID = 1, FirstName = "Jishan", LastName = "Siddique" },
         new student { StudentID = 2, FirstName = "Bharat", LastName = "Darji" },
         new student { StudentID = 3, FirstName = "Ravi", LastName = "Mori" },
         new student { StudentID = 4, FirstName = "Jay", LastName = "Singh" }
     };

    public IEnumerable<student> GetStudents()
    {
        return students;
    }
}
}
```

> > Finally: I would like 1 result like: student.StudentID = dr ["ID"]; student.FirstName = dr ["FirstName"]

Thank you all watch. Sorry for my bad english.

I'm searched result to google but not found

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Include your code as formatted `text`. Also, what is your question here. "Help me", isn't a question. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to help us help you.

Comment: Yest! I'm fixed the question. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes! I'm fixed. Thank you for the reminder

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using an ORM to do the plumbing code for you? EF is very popular but personally I prefer working with Dapper. Of course, you could create a list of `Student` and populate it in a loop (but in that case, you might want to use the more lightweight DataReader than a DataSet).

Comment: Is there a way for my code to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by getting value from the `DataRow`:

```
List<student> students = new List<student>();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in datatable.Rows)
{  

     students.Add(new student(){
         StudentID =dataRow["StudentID"];
         FirstName = dataRow["FirstName"] ;
         LastName = dataRow["LastName"] ;
     })
}
```

So, `students` collection will have all your students.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error IDE1007 The name 'students.Add' does not exist in the current context. WebApi2 C:\Users\obu\Downloads\WebApi2\WebApi2\WebApi2\myapi\StudentController.cs 14 Active

Comment: thank you. thank you so much thank you again :) It working!

Comment: @LongHoàngNguyễn I am glad to help you!